# Downloading the actual files of the language pack

Tags: windows-8

I just bought Asus laptop with Windows 8 in it. I am taking it back to my home country. We don't have very good internet connection in there. I could install the Russian language pack for Windows, but I don't have the files to install next time if reinstall the Windows. Is it possible to get it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're an MSDN subscriber you can download the 32 and 64-bit language pack DVDs. Otherwise as the official [Language Packs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win8) page states, "some language packs are sharable and some are not". Unfortunately it seems Russian falls into the latter category and thus can only be installed via the Control Panel Language applet:

[image: 1]

Comment: so I can't download the files?

Comment: Not legally unless you're an MSDN subscriber. What's the big deal anyway? If I follow the links to the sharable/downloadable languages, I don't see any bigger than ~7MB. Don't tell me internet connections in your country are *so* bad that such small files can't be downloaded!

Comment: My Windows 8 is legal, does it mean I am MSDN subscriber?

Comment: No, not automatically. It's a separate paid service.